# Pagination script added php page isn't loading or showing any error

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I tried to add a pagination script to my existing php page of sql queries.

But after adding the script the page is kept on loading without showing any content or error.

My code goes as:

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>

<?php // define how many results you want per page
$results_per_page = 10;

// find out the number of results stored in database
$sql10='SELECT * FROM smf_messages';
$result10 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql10);
$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result10);

// determine number of total pages available
$number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

// determine which page number visitor is currently on
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = 1;
} else {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
}

// determine the sql LIMIT starting number for the results on the displaying page
$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
?>
```

Now the sql query codes to get the data from the respective tables...

```
<?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM smf_log_digest WHERE note_type = 'topic' ORDER BY id_msg DESC LIMIT 420";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $number = $row2["id_msg"];
?>
```

This query relates to the content from which table to be retrieved..

```
<?php                                               
    // retrieve selected results from database and display them on page
    $sql20='SELECT * FROM smf_messages WHERE id_msg = $number AND id_board = 4 LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
    $result20 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql20);
    while($row20 = mysqli_fetch_array($result20)) {
    $member = $row20["id_member"];
    $replies = $row20["id_topic"];
?>
<?php
    $sqlstep1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM smf_log_digest WHERE note_type = 'reply' AND id_topic = $replies";
    $rowNumstep1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlstep1);
    $countstep1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowNumstep1);                             
?>

// Body
<article class="well btn-group-sm clearfix">
       <div class="topic-desc row-fluid clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-2 text-center publisher-wrap">
        <img src="assets/images/profile.png" alt="" class="avatar img-circle img-responsive">
        <h5><?php echo $row3["poster_name"]; ?></h5>
        <small class="online">Member</small>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
          <header class="topic-footer clearfix">
       <!-- end tags -->
          </header>
       <!-- end topic -->
          <h4> <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $row20['id_msg'];?>" style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo $row20["body"]; ?></a></h4>
           <div class="blog-meta clearfix">
            <small><a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $row20['id_msg'];?>"><?php echo  $countstep1["total"]; ?> Replies</a></small>
             <small><?php echo date('m/d/Y', $row20["poster_time"]); ?></small>
           </div>
           <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $row20['id_msg'];?>" class="readmore" title="">View the topic →</a>
        </div>
     </div>
</article>

//end of body

<?php 
    }
// display the links to the pages
for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
  echo '<a href="step1.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
}

?>

<?php     }
    } else {
    echo "";
    }
?>
```

Please note that the data base connections are all checked and are right..

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Why do you open and close PHP tags for each and every PHP code peace you don't have to do that unless you're combining HTML and PHP. Also I think you can `JOIN` both the `sql2` and `sql20` no need to run 2 queries. Ans you while loop `while($row20 = mysqli_fetch_array($result20))` can't see a closing bracket.

Answer (score -1):

add this on top then check for error.

`error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('desplay_errors','1');`

Comment: it came as `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in line 213` where the line 213 has code: `while($row20 = mysqli_fetch_array($result20)) {`

Comment: Query problem its return empty data check your query in db.

Comment: what does it mean

Comment: **$sql20='SELECT * FROM smf_messages WHERE id_msg = $number AND id_board = 4 LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;**

check this manually

Comment: But that query worked fine earlier.. before i added pagination